# SVN 'unbranched' files

Tags: svn, version-control, branch, cvs

So we're gradually moving all our projects across into SVN, from CVS.

One project in particular has two parallel development streams that share a lot of code, and they accomplish this with a neat trick on branch tags.

Some files are branched normally as they diverge on the different streams:

#### foo.c

- 1.18         --- HEAD, VERSION-1-BRANCH
- 1.15.2.10 --- VERSION-2-BRANCH

Others don't differ between the branches, and are 'shared' between the branches. Any updates automatically get included in *both* branches:

#### bar.c

- 1.25 --- HEAD, VERSION-1-BRANCH, VERSION-2-BRANCH

As far as I can see, there's no way to accomplish this same 'linking' of branches in subversion, on a file-by-file basis. Someone please tell me it isn't so?

Comment: That _feature_ in CVS seems very dangerous.

Comment: Agreed. The owner of this project is beginning to come round to the idea that splitting these common files (which mostly have lots of conditional compiles in them) would the the Right Thing.

Comment: Take a look at markdown formatting — much better than using HTML.

Comment: Thanks Roger - I'll do that now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Subversion 1.6 there has been support for the svn:externals property at a file level.  In previous versions it only worked on a directory basis

Comment: Thanks - also thanks to everyone who suggested externals. This seems to be the Right Thing, although it's not really usable in our precise situation. I don't have enough rep to + everyone, but thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

For sharing code between projects, SVN has [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that there is no way to do file sharing in this sense. You might want to look into using svn:externals though. This would require that you split the source into separate directories though...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could consider using svn:externals.

Sorry, I'm not sure if the previous three posters all hit the enter key at the same time or if there's a serious echo in the room. :-)